# Blender: White line appears on objects and lights are flickering

Tags: blender

I'm working in a team on a Blender project for a university course. We encountered two problems and don't really know how to solve them. It would be great if someone could help us.

1.) The first problem is that we have strange white lines appearing on some of our models which can be seen in this short video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4u7bx.jpg

2.) The second problem is that it appears as if our light sources would flicker but they should't. We don't know what causes this.

Here is the .blend file in case someone wants to have a look at it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16z7TuTzNEDBJAva5kGnU04yv1-83SQew/view?usp=sharing It would be fantastic if someone could help.

Thank you and many greets
Chris

Edit: Link updated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the first problem. It were some candles who apparantly cast a white line on some objects. I hope the second problem will also be solved by deleting the candles.

EDIT: Is there anything that anyone of you sees which causes this strange behavior with the candles?